# How to return the array when it's similar

Tags: php, arrays

I has two array look like this.

```
array1 = [  array("A"=> array("0"=>"1",
                              "1"=>"2",
                              "2"=>"3"),
                  "B"=>"1"),
            array("A"=> array("0"=>"1",
                              "1"=>"2"),
                   "B"=>"2")
                    ];

$array2 = array("A"=> array("0"=>"1",
                            "1"=>"2"),
                "B"=>"2",
                "C"=>"POP",
                "D"=>null);
```

Now i try to compare `$array1` and `$array2`.

 you will see `$array2` is same with `$array1` in `"A"` and `"B"`

This is my result i hope it's to be

```
$result = array("A"=> array("0"=>"1",
                            "1"=>"2"),
                "B"=>"2");
```

And last i use php(laravel)

I try to use

```
array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
```

but it gave a nothing

Comment: The arrays are not similar in any way. There's one additional nesting level in `$array1` compared to `$array2`.

Comment: If i want to compare $array1 to $array2 is it possible? OR I must make the $array1 just 1d array?

Comment: `$array1[0]` is closely related to `$array2`

Comment: $array1[0] is closely related to $array2 is not worked

Comment: @JustCarty you mean `$array1[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you define your own `array_intersect_assoc` as this:

```
function array_intersect_assoc_with_arrays($arr1, $arr2) {
    $ret = [];
    $commonkeys = array_intersect(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2)); // get all the keys that appear in both array
    foreach ($commonkeys as $key) {
        if (json_encode($arr1[$key]) == json_encode($arr2[$key])) //convert inner array to string so we can compare them
            $ret[$key] = $arr1[$key]; // if equal - set them in the response
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Now you can use it with:

```
$array1 = [array("A"=> array("0"=>"1", "1"=>"2", "2"=>"3"), "B"=>"1"), array("A"=> array("0"=>"1", "1"=>"2"), "B"=>"2")];
$array2 = array("A"=> array("0"=>"1", "1"=>"2"), "B"=>"2", "C"=>"POP", "D"=>null);

$res= [];              
foreach($array1 as $arr) { // for each sub-array get all the familiar fields
    $res = array_merge(array_intersect_assoc_with_arrays($arr, $array2), $res);
}
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [B] => 2
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's very helpful but i don't understand your code.Can you explain more please?

Comment: The problem is that `array_intersect_assoc` only works on array of string and not allow sub-array - I change it little bit to support also sub-array. Add comment to my code in the post. Please comment if you still has some un-clear lines